# How to read OpenSSL source

Tags: android, openssl, man-in-the-middle

I am trying to modify openssl apps to a static lib(for android use). So I need to understand how they generate MAKEFILE, how they generate so platform specify code, where is main program entry, etc.

My purpose(Man-in-the-middle attack):

1. Generate self singed root cert
2. Intercept https connection and generate cert singed by root cert

I have a few questions:

1. What tools they use for generating MAKEFILE
2. Could I modify openssl/apps to a static library call it in my app native code
3. Is there is tutorial help freshman to do this ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) is what you are looking for. You'll find there the steps to build openssl for Android and how to link the library statically.